# setting umask for a directory so that all directories, executable file(.sh , .cmd, .bat) are 750 and regular file 640

Tags: command-line-interface, file-permissions, user-permissions, umask, setfacl

need to create and change existing file and directory such that all directories and executable files(*.sh, *.bat, *.cmd ..) are 750 and regular file are 640 . I need to this in shell and python both.

I like to set umask to 027 while default is 022 for existing directory .... can't change default umask. Basically need to set umask directory specific

Comment: Hello, it's unclear whether you want to set umask, that controls how file permissions are set for newly created files, or change active permissions for *existing* files and directories. Please, edit the question clarifying this point.

Comment: I like to set umask to 027 while default is 022 for existing directory .... can't change default umask

Comment: you seem to not understand what umask is used for, i would recommend you to read this article https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't set umask for a directory, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/44539/667611) analogous Q&A.

Let's read [`man umask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) to see what your options are:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> umask() sets the calling process's file mode creation mask (umask) to mask & 0777 (i.e., only the file permission bits of mask
>   are used), and returns the previous value of the mask.
>
> The  umask  is  used by open(2), mkdir(2), and other system calls that create files to modify the permissions placed on newly
>   created files or directories.  Specifically, permissions in the umask
>   are turned off from the mode
>          argument to open(2) and mkdir(2).
>
> Alternatively, if the parent directory has a default ACL (see acl(5)), the umask is ignored, the default ACL is inherited, the
>   permission bits are set based on the inherited ACL, and permission
>   bits absent in the mode  argument are turned off.  For example, the following default ACL is equivalent to a umask of 022:
>
> ```
> u::rwx,g::r-x,o::r-x
> ```
>
> Combining the effect of this default ACL with a mode argument of 0666 (rw-rw-rw-), the resulting file permissions would be 0644
>   (rw-r--r--).

I would say you have three options here:

1. Leave umask alone and periodically run a script that sets the wanted permissions for files and directories.
2. Run `umask 027` when you are creating files or directories in that particular location - this will affect the current process. Run `umask 022` when you are done.
3. Enable and use ACLs. Since you tagged this question `setfacl`, you are probably already contemplating this method:

   ```
   setfacl -Rdm u::rwx,g::r-x,o::--- .
   touch a
   mkdir b
   ```

   Run `ls -al` and `getfacl *` to see the results:

   ```
   -rw-r-----  a
   drwxr-x---+ b

   # file: a
   user::rw-
   group::r--
   other::---

   # file: b
   user::rwx
   group::r-x
   other::---
   default:user::rwx
   default:group::r-x
   default:other::---
   ```

**Note:** Default permissions don't differentiate based on file extensions: if you want .sh, .cmd and .bat to have 750 and other files 640, your best option is 1. above.

Comment: umask can be used for files and directories

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk Thank you for your comment. Please expand on this information, since by reading man it looks like umask affects the parent process and not a specific file or directory.

Comment: check this link https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html read this section "Explain Octal umask Mode 022 And 002" go change umask to something else than 002 such as 004, create a file and folder before and after the change and see permissions between them not being the same for both file and directory. umask has always been used to setup default permissions for both files and folder for aslong as i have worked with it.

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk It is apparent from the info you posted that umask affects permissions for files and folders created from the current process. The question was about setting default permissions on a directory that any process (e.g. a different user) would respect.